# Does cycling make Anterior Pelvic Tilt worse?

Tags: bicycling, apt

I have APT and I'm wondering whether cycling can help fix it. Or, does it make it worse?
I'm also looking for some sports that can help fix my condition because I get fed up quickly when just doing exercises.

Comment: It's debatable whether anterior pelvic tilt is even a real disorder, versus just quacks pathologising normal anatomic variations. Have you actually been having any symptoms which have been causing you problems? Or did someone just tell you that you have APT and that this is a bad thing?

Comment: I just can't stand it, it's bothering me a lot especially when buying clothes . That's why I want to get rid of it ASAP. But the problem is that I don't have the required willpower to start excercising and changing..

Comment: How does the posture of your pelvis and lower back bother you when buying clothes?

Comment: @DavidScarlett because I want to wear clothes that don't give the impression that I've APT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycling won't necessarily make it better or worse - there are lots of variables including the type of riding you do and your riding position - but given that you're bent over with your hip flexors shortened, I wouldn't count on it making things any better.

If you want to fix an anterior pelvic tilt then you really need to do some specific corrective exercises, whether you like it or not. In APT you tend to see the following:

- Lower back muscles too short/tight
- Hip flexors (specifically iliacus) too short/tight
- Hamstrings too weak
- "Lower abdominals" too weak. I put lower abdominals in quotes, as although this is a commonly-used term, there are no separate upper/lower abdominal muscles. What you're really talking about here is the ability of your abdominal/core muscles to stabilise and posterially tilt your pelvis.

So a typical remedial strategy would be:

- Strengthen hamstrings
- Stretch iliacus
- Exercises to relax lower back muscles (I don't recommend flexion stretches for the lower back)
- Exercises that improve the ability of your core muscles to stabilise and posterially tilt your pelvis (e.g. plank, pelvic tilts)

As always, consulting a fitness professional with some knowledge of corrective exercise is recommended.

Comment: Thank you!  But how much time do you recommend I do this kind of exercises? And should it be once per day or twice?

Comment: Once per day should be fine - I imagine a suitable routine should only take 20 minutes or so.